# Databind jqGrid with Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, jqgrid

Is possible to use Vue.js databinding  in jqGrid?
I tried to use formatter property of colModel but anything.
Is there a sample of this?

Thanks.

Comment: Which grid actually you mean - jqGrid or jsGrid? - that are quite different products. In case you use jqGrid which version is used?

Comment: I use jqGrid 4.6.0 version

Comment: This is a very old version and it is not recommend to use it, since it is not supported.  What is the problem you have? Does the grid not load the data or it does not format it in a way you want (as described) - that are quite different things.

Comment: Thanks Tony. I'm new with Vue and I have an old project with jqGrid that I would like to update. After your comment I think to use all View components; or have you to suggest other tools similar to jqGrid  (to combine with Vue)?

Comment: I think there is a Vue.js grid.  Not sure for the name just search for it.